# How to overlap 2 transparent divs?

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar set to "fixed" positioning at the top of my web page with a transparency of 75%.  I have another div that holds all of my text/content that also has a transparency of 75%.  However, when the "content" div overlaps with the navigation bar, I want the overlapped area of the "content" div to not be there, so to speak.  I also want there to be a tiny gap between where the "content" div and the navigation bar would overlap.

#### When it's scrolled up:

[image: Scrolled up]

#### When it's overlapping:

[image: Overlapping]

In the 2nd screenshot, I want the part of the "content" div that is overlapping to go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could put the "content" div in a transparent "container" div that was fixed just below the navigation and 100% wide/tall.  Then put overflow:auto on the "container" and overflow:hidden on the body.

The "container" div will effectively become the body of your page and all scrolling will happen within it, instead of the body. So it should then look like the "content" div disappears before it reaches the navigation while you're scrolling down.

This may or may not be practical depending on the rest of your page, but i think it might work, give or take a few other css tweaks u may need.

Comment: I tried it out, but it needs some tweaking.  The container div scrolls down with the page, so it doesn't actually work as it should.

Comment: If you put `position:fixed` on the container div it shouldn't scroll.  Same as your navigation div, if i understand your situation correctly.  Then give it a 'top' declaration that sets it just below the bottom of the navigation.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

to overlap.

1st div

```
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
```

2nd div to over lap the 1st div

```
position:absolute;
z-index:3;
```

z-index will make elements overlap but it must have the position
you can use fixed or relative also.